# C# + Visual Studio : Can I create multiple selenium test through unit test project type in one solution?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, visualstudio

This is a newbie question as I am very new to selenium and automation basics. I am creating my selenium tests through Visual Studio, with the help of C#. I have some confusion on these areas:

1. I am doing self study on how to create scripts using Selenium with C#. Why all of the tutorials are written thru Unit Test Project type when all I want to create is only regression/functional testing?
2. So I created a library in the console app project, then added a new unit test type so I could pull all my classes/methods in that library and in the same directory. Is it acceptable to create multiple unit test project in that same solution? What would be the drawback? I am planning to at least automate 10 apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Functional tests need a way to get run in batches. The unit-testing frameworks help with this, also they include assert functions to verify results. So the unit-testing framework is reused as test-runner in your examples.
2. Better is to create a test project in the solution of the application. This way the tests get versioned with the application and are close by. If you have shared test code between all your tests create a single shared DLL / solution for that instead and reference it.